# xcode update class after modifying data model

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode5

Is there an automatic way using XCode5, to update the class definitions after modifying the core data model (of course I'm talking about the classes regarding the data model ;) ).

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147016/better-way-to-recreate-the-class-definition-after-modifying-core-data-model), but the solution was not satisfying and since xcode 5 is out, maybe there is something new.

Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally implement all my custom code of managed object subclasses in **categories**. This is already part of my normal workflow and counts as an established best practice.

Now regenerating your class definitions is nothing more than choosing **one** menu command. I think this is an acceptable degree of automation.

Beats any third party framework import, learning curve and maintenance.

Comment: Sorry I missed the automation it was under my nose. Just to make it clear: Create new NSManagedObject with the Entity you want and then overwrite the class. If you used Categories as @Mundi said you should be in the clear.

Comment: To clarify above comment: you either **add** a new entity to your model; then you just **generate** a **new** class.  Or you **modify** an existing entity; then you **overwrite** the existing class.