# iOS Preserve custom methods in classes after recreating from core data

Tags: ios, class, core-data, auto-generate

I am looking for someway how to preserve methods which I add to my classes which are generated from Core Data. It should be mainly init methods but It could be other methods too. When I was looking best approach for this I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147016/better-way-to-recreate-the-class-definition-after-modifying-core-data-model) but It's a little old and I hope there is better solution now. So exists better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think creating Categories like suggested in the accepted answer on the question you're referring to is a valid approach. The other option is to stop generating the files when you've reached a stable point for your entities. Normally they shouldn't keep changing too much (since that will introduce challenges with migrations etc). And if the changes are small enough (like adding a new property etc) its easy to do this manually.

You could also have a look at [Moogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) which I know a lot of ppl who are happy with.